# Using PHP to Extract Multiple Phone numbers from a string or file

Tags: php, regex

I have a huge text file that is a copy and paste job from a PDF phone bill.  I need to extract each phone number and put it in an array so that I can insert the numbers into a DB table and run some queries on it.

I am using preg_match_all to try and match all of the numbers and failing miserably.  Here is the code I have:

```
$phone_list = "13:26 (415)332-5555 13:49 (925)398-5555 13:56 (415)294-3333 14:17 (707)538-2222 14:23 (415)233-1111 14:28 (415)294-0000 14:34";
preg_match_all('/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/',$phone_list,$matches);
```

...Which returns nothing.  If I shorten the $phone_list to:

```
$phone_list = "(415)294-0000";
```

...I get a result.  What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the anchors `^` and `$` - they force the regex to match the entire string.

`^` means "Assert that the match starts at the start of the string".

`$` means "Assert that the match ends at the end of the string".

Comment: Thanks Tim...this was exactly what I need.  Sometimes RegEx feels like Sanskrit to me. :)